# Merging each instance mask back to the original image Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I am having a bunch of mask (object is white, non-object is black) bounded by their bounding box as a separate image, and I'm trying to put them back to their original positions on the original image. What I have in mind right now is:

1. Create a black image of the same size of the original image.
2. Add the value of each mask with the value of the coordinate of the bounding box on the original image together.

Could anyone tell me if I am heading in the right path, is there any better way to do this?.

Below is roughly my implementation

```
import cv2
black_img = np.zeros((height,width)) # A image that is of the size of the original but is all black
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png")
bbox = [x1, y1, x2, y2] # Pretend that this is a valid bounding box coordinate on the original image
black_img[y1:y2, x1:x2] += mask
```

For example:
I have the first image which is one of my masks. Its size is of the same of the bounding box on the original image. I'm trying merge each mask back together so that I achieved something like the second image.

One of the mask:
[image: pred]

After merging all the mask:
[image: gt]

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have a mask with has white (object) and black(background) values. You want to only show the objects and set the rest of the image as black. is this correct?

Comment: It's close. I do have masks that have white (object) and black(background) values. The thing that I have many masks, each mask represents an object in the original picture. I want to put all of the mask together in a single gray-scale image that is of the same size of the original picture, and each object must be in their original position.

Comment: So, for each small mask, you have a corresponding bounding box. And you want to aggregate those small bounding boxes. Your code is pretty close then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the mask is 0 and 1's and your image is grayscale. Also, for each `small_mask`, you have a corresponding `bbox`.

```
mask = np.zeros((height,width))
for small_mask, bbox in zip(masks, bboxes):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = bbox
    mask[y1:y2, x1:x2] += small_mask
mask = ((mask>=1)*255.0).astype(np.uint8)
```

Now you combined all the small masks together.

The last line:
My assumption was somehow two masks may intersect. So those intersection may have values more than 1. `mask >= 1` tells me that the pixels that are more than 0 are gonna be all on.

I multiplied that by `255.0` because I wanted to make it white. You won't be able to see 1's in a grayscale image.

`(mask >= 1)*255.0` expanded the range from [0-1] to [0-255]. But this value is float which is not image type.

`.astype(np.uint8)` converts the `float` to `uint8`. Now you can do all the image operations without any problem. When it is float, you may face a lot of issues, like plotting, saving, all will cause some issues.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, isn't multiplying the gray scale image with the mask required the gray-scale image and the mask to be the same in size? I think you misinterpreted my question, I will make some edition to the main post to clarify what I am trying to achieve

Comment: I see, you basically have bounding boxes, not the whole mask. Yes, it seems I misinterpreted. Let me update the code a bit

Comment: Can you please explain the last line, I don't quite get that?